# How can I update vue cli version?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I want to create a project on Vue Project Manager. When I try, I see that error message;

**"vue create is a Vue CLI 3 only command and you are using Vue CLI 2.9.6."**

This is my vue --version output: **@vue/cli 4.0.5.**

How can I fix this?

My system configuration is as follow:

> Ubuntu 18.04
>   Npm 6.13.0 
>   Node 10.16.3

Answer (score 6):

Uninstall it first with

```
npm uninstall vue-cli -g or yarn global remove vue-cli
```

Then install it again with

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
# OR
yarn global add @vue/cli
```

The package name changed from vue-cli to @vue/cli that is why you need to uninstall it first and install it again.

Comment: Could it be the same issue like this

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-version-says-older-version-than-i-just-installed/78577

and try to restart your machine too

Comment: I have to use `sudo yarn global add @vue/cli`

Answer (score 3):

First remove the existing package from globally **Make sure you have administrator priviledge**

```
npm uninstall vue-cli -g
```

Then -

I believe this will work and install latest version

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

Reference - https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html

Once you done Verify

```
vue --version
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked on my work approach, uninstall the vue and reinstall using the steps in the documentation. [enter link description here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.htmlhttps://)

1 - remove vue: `sudo npm uninstall -g vue-cli`
2 - install using: `sudo npm install -g @vue/clisudo npm uninstall -g vue-cli`

Answer (score 0):

I found that in my case, I have had @vue/cli installed using `npm install -g` and also `yarn add global`.

for that reason even when I did `yarn global remove @vue/cli`, I still would get result from `vue --version` resulted in: -old-version-number-.

I had to to also uninstall it with:

```
npm uninstall vue-cli -g
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have more than one versions of  **vue**.

Delete the **@vue** folder from this directory

`C:\Users\Muhammad Abbas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`

After that run this command

`npm install -g @vue/cli`

This will solve the Problem

Answer (score 0):

You could install 'vue' somewhere by yarn, which put this 'vue' in your path ahead of `/usr/local/bin`. so do this first:

```
which vue
```

if this output is not the one you just reinstalled, just remove it. After this, run `which vue` again to check, and `vue -V` to confirm it has been upgrade to what you've installed.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like some files may be broken or corrupted. So first, I'd suggest you uninstall/ remove the @vue/cli.

Then reinstall it, and you should be golden.

Here is a one-liner that would remove @vue/cli and install the newest vue/cli.

```
npm uninstall -g @vue-cli && npm i -g @vue/cli
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

### The recommended way to start a Vite-powered Vue project.
Visit GitHub
https://github.com/vuejs/create-vue

**I made it myself with this method:**

1=> npm uninstall -g vue-cli

2=> npm i -g @vue/cli

3=> vue create myproject

4=> cd myproject

5=> npm run serve